# What's the English for different kinds of notebooks?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

What are the common terms for these kinds of notebooks?

For the one that has lines:
[image]

And for the one that has squares: [image]

Comment: Those are not notebooks. They are types of sheets in a pad. yellow pads are the most well known.

Answer (score 2):

In British English the first is feint-ruled paper or simply ruled paper.

English: feint-ruled paper
Definition of 'feint-ruled paper'
feint-ruled paper
in British English
(ˈfeɪntˌruːld ˈpeɪpə)
NOUN
writing paper with light horizontal lines printed across at regular intervals
Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

**Feint-ruled paper or simply ruled paper**

[image]

**Squared paper**

[image]

**Graph paper**

[image]

Comment: Ruled paper is the same in the US, too. I am going to start only posting BrE responses.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the first one a lined notebook and the second a grid notebook.

Answer (score 0):

legal pad

Definition of legal pad
: a writing tablet of **ruled yellow paper** that is usually 8.5 by 14 inches (about 22 by 36 centimeters) [term: ruled paper]

Merriam Webster.

[Term] The other is graph or grid  paper.

[graph or grid paper](https://www.math-drills.com/graphpaper.php)

This latter one can be looseleaf or in a notebook. The first only comes as a pad or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I know the first one as **ruled** paper, supported by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ruled) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruled):

> (of paper) marked with parallel straight lines

I know the squared one as **quadrille** paper, supported by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quadrille) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrille):

> Marked with squares or rectangles

It differs from graph paper by being evenly ruled, whereas graph paper has stronger 5th and/or 10th lines.